# El programa dejo de funcionar

Tags: c, funciones

resulta que estoy haciendo un programa que genere un array con numeros aleatorios, el programa funcionaba, pero le cambie algunas cosas para mejorarlo. y se ejecuta pero despues de generar 2 valores aleatorios para compararlos en el array, me aparece una ventaja "dejo de funcionar" . estoy trabajando en el metodo "numeros", ese metodo va a buscar si el numero generado está en el array y si lo está, que ese numero se cambie por "178" qu es el codigo ASCII que elegi utilizar para que lo muestre tachado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <gotoxy.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    int numeros(int bingo1[5][5], int i);

    int Aleatorio (int inicial)
    {   
        return rand() % 15 + inicial; 
    }

    bool Verificador(int numero, int columna, int bingo1 [5][5], int colum, int k, int a) 
    {
        int j, q;
        if (k==2){ j=colum; q=a;}else{j=columna; q=numero;}
            for(int i=4 ;i>=0;i--)
            {
                    if(q==bingo1[j][i])
                        {   
                                if(k==2){numeros(0,i); }    
                            return true;
                        }
            }   
    return false;
    }

    int carton1 ()
    {   
        int x=3, bingo1 [5][5];
        for (int a=1; a<=2;a++)
        {
            int  fila, columna, y=3, numero, inicial=1;
            srand(time(NULL));
            for (columna=0; columna<5; columna++)
            {
                for(fila=0; fila<5; fila++)     
                {
                        do
                        {
                            numero= Aleatorio(inicial);
                        }
                        while(Verificador(numero, columna, bingo1, 0,0,0) == true);
                        bingo1[columna][fila]=numero;           
                }
            inicial=inicial + 15;
            }
            if (a==1){gotoxy(11,2); printf("BINGO | %d |",a);}
            else{gotoxy(48,2); printf("BINGO | %d |", a);}
            for (fila=0; fila<5; fila++)
            {
                for (columna=0; columna<5; columna++)       
                {
                    gotoxy(x,y); printf("| %d |", bingo1[columna][fila]);
                    x=x+5;
                }
            y=y + 2;
            x=x-25;
            }
        x=x+37;
        }
    numeros(bingo1, 0);
    }
int numeros(int bingo1[5][5], int i)
{
int a, fil, colum, k=2, n=3,m=3;
    for (int c=1; c<=25; c++)
    {
        a=rand() % 75 + 1; 
        gotoxy(20,15);printf("EL NUMERO ALEATORIO ES:  %d  ", a);
        gotoxy(20,16);system("PAUSE");
            for (colum=0; colum<5; colum++)     
                {
                        if( Verificador(0,0,bingo1,colum,k,a) == true);
                        {
                            bingo1[colum][i]=178;
                        }
                }
            for (fil=0; fil<5; fil++)
            {
                for (colum=0; colum<5; colum++)     
                {
                    gotoxy(n,m); printf("| %d |", bingo1[colum][fil]);
                    n=n+5;
                }
            m=m + 2;
            n=n-25;
            }       
    }

}
    int main ()
    {

        carton1();
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con esta función:

```
int numeros(int bingo1[5][5], int i)
```

El siguiente código no es demasiado oportuno:

```
if(q==bingo1[j][i])
{
    if(k==2){numeros(0,i); }
    return true;
}
```

El primer parámetro que le estás pasando a `numeros`  es 0, lo que se traduce (en este caso) en un puntero nulo... en el momento en el que en `numeros` intentas acceder a algún valor de ese puntero el Sistema Operativo matará tu aplicación para evitar que corrompa memoria que no te pertenece.

Entiendo que lo correcto sería hacer:

```
if(k==2){numeros(bingo1,i); }
```

Peeero tu programa es un poco caótico:

- Las variables no dan idea de su utilidad
- ¿Por qué `k==2`?
- La tabulación es extraña y no ayuda a entender los ámbitos

Comment: La Función de "Verificador" es verificar que si el número que se manda, existe en la matriz [5][5], si existe entonces retornará un valor "True", si no existe "False'. Ésta Función , yo la invoco en dos métodos, los cuales son "Carton1" y "Números", pero en el caso de "Números" yo quiero que se haga una acción distinta , por lo que mandó a "K=2" como parámetro a "Verificador" , entonces a la hora de ejecutarse el método de  "Verificador" , él primero detectará , cuál de los dos métodos está entrando, por medio a un "If" .

Comment: @NIGGAV3N0M0N para esos usos deberias plantearte usar `enum`. Lo mas importante es que el código sea legible... si te toca volver al codigo un tiempo después te vas a desesperar

Comment: @NIGGAV3N0M0N en cualquier caso piensa que si su función es verificar si un numero se encuentra en la matriz... su funcionamiento debería ser el mismo en ambos casos... estas mezclando responsabilidades

Comment: si, pero el caso es que yo necesito que en el método de "Números" me pase el número de la fila en el que se encontró el numero, algo que no debe suceder cuando llamo a "Verificador" en "Carton1" ya que no es necesario.

Comment: @NIGGAV3N0M0N a ver, tu puedes hacer que la función `Verificador` te diga si el número ya existe y, de existir, su posición... y luego tu ya utilizas la información que necesitas en cada caso... siempre **fuera** de la función `Verificador`

Comment: Si, veo que me está dando un poco de problema. Buscaré otra forma de hacerlo